# Can a Brexit deal be accepted after Brexit?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union

There is the possibility that the UK leaves the EU without any deal in place, not because anybody wants it, but because of just running out of time.

In that case, if the UK government eventually figured out that they want to accept the deal that May and EU put on the table, would it be possible at all that this would be accepted, say a few weeks after Brexit?

Comment: It could in theory, but it would also look exactly like May's deal. So the question would then be why bother, since it got rejected twice (and possibly 3 or 4 times by then)?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's mostly a matter of semantics what do you want to call any deal after a no-deal Brexit, "managed no-deal" etc. In the current game of chicken, the EU has rejected any [piecemeal mini-deals after a no-deal Brexit](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2018-12-17/eu-to-rule-out-managed-no-deal-as-bloc-boosts-brexit-planning) and announced [unilateral measures after a no-deal Brexit](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2019/mar/25/brussels-confirms-return-of-border-checks-under-no-deal-brexit).

It's not clear to me if the EU legal framework allows an approval of the (non-euphemistically) big deal (agreed between May and the EU, but insofar rejected by MPs) after the Brexit date has legally passed; as you probably know the date has been pushed forward, by legally binding mutual agreement of the UK and EU. Usually, if there's political will, a legal way is found in such matters.